# How to get caption/text of button in WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, caption

I have the following HTML code for "Save" button:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Sure to change global settings?')" value="Save" name="submit">
```

I want to retrieve the caption of button. I used the following code to do that:

```
String actualButtonCaption = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Save']")).getText();
```

I also used the absolute xpath as below:

```
String actualButtonCaption = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/input")).getText();
```

But unfortunately, no text was retrieved. Blank/empty text was found. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`getAttribute` method could be used to retrieve the attribute values.

In this case following would return the caption:

`driver.findElement(By.XPath("//input[@name='submit']")).getAttribute("value");`

Comment: Didn't see the answer before so added mine. :D

Comment: Hey it will be `By.xpath` not `By.XPath`.. can't edit as we need min 6 char to have an edit.

Answer (score 1):

try associating an `ID` with input and then find element by ID. If text comes out, then there is a problem with xpath, you can analyze the exact run time xpath by using plugin of Firefox.

Comment: There is no id of element, that's why I used xpath. And I have checked the xpath used is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

This should work -

```
String actualButtonCaption = driver.findElement(By.name("Submit")).getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: Yes, the concept is as same as Pani Kumar.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution by using JavaScript. The code is as below:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String ss = (String)jse.executeScript("var x=document.getElementsByName('submit')[0].value; return x");
System.out.println("Caption of Save button: " + ss);
```

It works fine. The caption of button is printed as "Save"